# Removing button from google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have an issue trying to delete a button from a google sheet, I have a script that takes the "Main Sheet" and converts it to pdf and then send it as an attachment everything works but i cannot delete the button it appears in the pdf "Save changes" i searched and found out that buttons are images therefore i tried the following :

```
  var images = newSpreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getImages();
  images.map(function(img){img.remove();});
```

but this didn't work, below is the current code:

```
 var originalSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
 var newSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.create("text"+a);
 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
 
  sheet = originalSpreadsheet.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.copyTo(newSpreadsheet);
  newSpreadsheet.getSheetByName('Sheet1').activate();
  newSpreadsheet.deleteActiveSheet();
  newSpreadsheet.getActiveSheet();
  var width = newSpreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getLastColumn();
  var Height = newSpreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getLastRow();
 newSpreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getRange('A1:F50').copyTo(newSpreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getRange('A1').activate(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);

 newSpreadsheet.getActiveSheet().hideColumns(8, width-8); 
 newSpreadsheet.getActiveSheet().deleteColumns(8, width-8);
 newSpreadsheet.getActiveSheet().hideColumns(8, width-8);

  var images = newSpreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getImages();
  images.map(function(img){img.remove();});

SpreadsheetApp.flush();
```

Answer (score 2):

#### Modification points:

- Although I'm not sure about the detail of `this didn't work`, in the current stage, there are 2 kinds of buttons for Google Spreadsheet. One is an image. This has already been mentioned in your question. Another is a drawing.
- Your script removes the images in the active sheet. But the drawings cannot be removed with your script. I thought that the reason of your issue might be due to this.

So in this answer, I would like to suggest the method for removing the drawings from the active sheet.

#### Sample script:

```
const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
sheet.getImages().forEach(img => img.remove());  // Remove images.
sheet.getDrawings().forEach(drawing => drawing.remove());  // Remove drawings.
```

#### Note:

- I think that in your script, `foEach` might be suitable, because the method of `remove()` returns no values.

#### References:

- [getImages()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getImages())
- [getDrawings()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getdrawings)
- [remove() of Class OverGridImage](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/over-grid-image#remove())
- [remove() of Class Drawing](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/drawing#remove())

Comment: I've been searching for a script to remove drawings. I've tried several, and yours is the only one that works. It's also the most elegant. Thank you!